# Implicit conversion of 'C *' to 'A *' not allowed in function C::add()

Tags: c++

while compiling the following code I got an error message like "Implicit conversion of 'C *' to 'A *' not allowed in function C::add()".

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class A
{    
    public:
    int a;
    int get()
    {
       return 10;
    }
};
class B:protected A
{
   ..............................

};
class C: public B
{
    public:
    void add()
    {
        cout<<a;
        cout<<get();
    }
};
void main()
{
    C ob;
    ob.add();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `main` must return `int` in C++.

Comment: I ran your example and could not reproduce your warning: https://godbolt.org/z/rdRgXk

Answer (score 1):

I did not get any error while running this after I added "using namespace std" after line 2 in your code.

Complete code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class A
{    
    protected:
    int a;
    int get()
    {
       return 10;
    }
};
class B:protected A
{
  // ..............................

};
class C:public B
{
    public:
    void add()
    {
       cout<<a;
       cout<<get();
    }
};
int main()
{
    C ob;
    ob.add();
    //getch();
}
```

Or u can use

```
std::cout<<a;
std::cout<<get();
```

Comment: _Check code at `https://ideone.com/ubwq6y`_ Please, paste code from [https://ideone.com/ubwq6y](https://ideone.com/ubwq6y) into your answer. (Links might get lost over time.) And, btw. links should be formatted as links but not as souce code (even if they refer to source code).

Comment: Thanks for your replay. This error occurred in Tc compiler (windows)